# How to Reduce Error Term

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, random-variable, error

My question is "What could you do if you wanted to reduce the error term (e)?  I know the error term is basically the distance between the line and the point but I don't know how you would reduce it.

The problem is:

> The Postal Service is attempting to reduce the number of complaints made by the public against its workers. In order to facilitate this task, a staff analyst for the Service regresses the number of complaints lodged against an employee last year (Y) on the hourly wage of the employee for the year (X). She obtains the following results: Y = 10.2 - 1.6X + e r2 = .73 Syx = 1.1 sb = .87 n = 348

Comment: To get useful help, please revise this question to provide some context. Your readers will want to know something about the data, the model, and what options you have in terms of modifying the dataset or the model.

Comment: Sure!  I thought I was doing pretty well but that question caught me off guard because I don't think we ever discussed it in class.

Comment: 19. The Postal Service is attempting to reduce the number of complaints made by the public against its workers.  In order to facilitate this task, a staff analyst for the Service regresses the number of complaints lodged against an employee last year (Y) on the hourly wage of the employee for the year (X).  She obtains the following results:
 Y = 10.2 - 1.6X + e
 r2 = .73 Syx = 1.1  sb = .87   n = 348

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, the error are errors of prediction--the closer you are to the observed value with your regression equation, the smaller the error. Therefore, to reduce the error, you need to improve your prediction. To do so, you would add other predictors to your model that are related to your dependent variable.

Comment: (1) or look for non-linearity in the terms (2) or explore possible interactions

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know why that didn't cross my mind, it seems like such an easy question now.  Duh moment!